# What is the relationship between the width/height specified for a d3.select element and the actual drawing area?

Tags: d3.js, word-cloud

I am using d3.cloud to make some word clouds. I do not understand the relationship between setting the width and height of the svg image, and the "transform" action. I set the svg size to be 1200 x 600, but the actual word cloud is only 590x 290.

My code for the word cloud:

```
function prep_drawing(data) {

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
      width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  
  // append the svg object to the body of the page
  var svg = d3.select("#wordly_wordcloud").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  
  // Constructs a new cloud layout instance. It run an algorithm to find the position of words that suits your requirements
  // Wordcloud features that are different from one word to the other must be here
  var layout = d3.layout.cloud()
    .size([width, height])
    .words(data.map(function(d) { return {text: d.word, size:d.size, color:d.color, url:d.url}; }))
    .padding(5)        //space between words
    .rotate(function() { return 0; })
    .fontSize(function(d) { return parseFloat(d.size) * 250; })      // font size of words
    .on("end", draw);
  layout.start();
  
  function draw(words) {
      svg
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + layout.size()[0] / 2 + "," + layout.size()[1] / 2 + ")")
          .selectAll("text")
            .data(words)
          .enter().append("text")
            .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size; })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-family", "Impact")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .append("a")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.url; })
            .attr("style", function(d) { return "fill:"+d.color+";"; })
            .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
    }
}
```

Here is the output from the chrome developer tool Elements section:

```
<div id="wordly_wordcloud">
   <svg width="1200" height="600">
      <g transform="translate(10,10)">
        <g transform="translate(590,290)">
           <text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-201,-78)rotate(0)" style="font-size: 150px; fill: rgb(144, 12, 0); font-family: Impact;"><a xlink:href="wordcloud.html?name=descriptions&amp;word=story" style="fill:rgb(144, 12, 0);">story</a></text>
...other <text> elements remove for clarity
</g></g></svg></div>
```

Is it possible to increase the size of the "g" transform area, which seems to be the drawing area for the word cloud.

I keep running into the issue that some of the "high frequency" words are are not drawn because they do not fit into the 590 x 290 "g" box. My word frequencies are normalized to the range 0-1, and I multiply the frequency by a factor between 150-350 to get legible words. It is not clear to me how to balance the relationship between the specified width/height and the multiplier for the word frequency to insure all the words are displayed and they are legible.

Is there a better way to specify the font size based on word frequency?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a known issue of d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/issues/36). One solution is to recursively try again until all words fit:

```
function drawCloud () {
  d3.layout.cloud()
  .on("end", function(output) {
      if (word.length !== output.length) { 
           drawCloud(range_max - 5);
           return undefined;  
      }
      else { draw(output); } // your draw function here
   })
  .start();
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for the code and link. As I said, I am very new to d3 and d3.cloud. In your code, what is the range_max value?